# Kubernetes how to isolate a pod from traffic path

Tags: kubernetes

For example, I have a pod (owned by a deployment) encouter high memory usage.
Is it possible to detach a pod from deployment, so:

1. New pod will be created to serve the incoming traffic. So that produciton recovers ASAP.
2. Old pod will keep running in Kuberentes for future investigation. It does not receive any traffic to minize the production imppact.

Is that possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly. But, if you fancy messing around a lot, you could destroy the pod/service's existing network connection (cluster IP, node port, ingress, etc.), deploy another copy of the service, but edit its name first and then attach it to the same network config. This would give you a break in service, but if you script it and do the new deployment before rerouting the network then it wouldn't necessarily be for very long.